# using jquery .html(), i cant pass an id through to a function

Tags: javascript

sorry if confusing.. but i am this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.yo1").click(function(){
    $("div.class1").html("<h1>&nbsp;</h1><h1><br /><select id='multi2' style='width:193px;'></select><br /></h1><button>Pick Class</button>")
  });
});
```

and 'multi2' can't be found .. do i have to pass a parameter or variable?.  here is the function to get multi2

```
function childless() {

var s = document.getElementById('multi2');
var ar = [1,2,3];
for(var i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text = ar[i];
option.value = ar[i];
s.options[i] = option;
}

}
```

it works if i dont change the div, any ideas?

Comment: How do you trigger `function childless()`?

Comment: Creating child elements by setting the innerHTML of the parent will cause problems with finding them by ID later.  You'll have a better chance of it working if you actually create a new `<select>` node and insert it into the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.yo1").click(function(){
        $("div.class1").html("<h1>&nbsp;</h1><h1><br /><select id='multi2' style='width:193px;'></select><br /></h1><button>Pick Class</button>");
        childless(); // <---call childless() after the HTML content has been added.
    });
});
```

Although I'd wonder why you want to recreate the content with each click of `div.class1`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the childless() function can't be called unless button.yo1 has been clicked

Comment: right.. so then i tried to set document.getElementbyId('yo1').onclick = childless() .. and same result..

Comment: first, childless() is for calling the function! you'll have to pass it without the ().

but you're already bindind something to the click on button.yo1 with jQuert so I would say: copy the content of your function there.